# SQL and 2 complex join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to optimize a SQL query with MySQL 5.5, regarding 2 separates requests. I'd like to have one single request at the end if possible.

I have a DocumentType table (see schema at the end of this question).
I'd like to display "3 DocumentInstance on 5 uploaded for Program #4" for instance.

To count the total of document per program, I have this query:

```
select p.id as programId, count(dt.id) as totalDocPerProgram
from DocumentType dt
join DocumentTypeInProgram dtip on dtip.documentType_id=dt.id
join Program p on dtip.program_id=p.id
group by p.id
```

To count how many docs the user had already uploaded, classified by program, the following query returns the list of userSession and how many docs he did uploaded previously  :

```
select p2.id as programId, wsc2.id as userSession, count(di2.id) as uploadedDocs
from DocumentType dt2
join DocumentInstance di2 on di2.documentType_id=dt2.id
join WebsiteCase wsc2 on di2.websiteCase_id=wsc2.id
left join Program p2 on p2.id=wsc2.program_id
group by wsc2.id
```

**My Question:** 
Is it possible to have one single query that would return for each program, the totalDocPerProgram and how many document have been already uploaded ? 
And would it be possible to have something like : "Please upload 2 more Documents for Program #3" ?

Thanks for your help guys,

Nicolas

Here is the Database SQL definition script

```
CREATE TABLE `DocumentType` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lifetime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxDocumentSize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Program` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `DataTypeForProgram` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cardinality` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataType_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKA6CED6BFFCC6BB96` (`program_id`),
  KEY `FKA6CED6BF17C2EE7E` (`dataType_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKA6CED6BF17C2EE7E` FOREIGN KEY (`dataType_id`) REFERENCES `DataType` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKA6CED6BFFCC6BB96` FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`) REFERENCES `Program` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `WebsiteCase` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creationDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_Program` (`program_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Program` FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`) REFERENCES `Program` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `DocumentInstance` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documentType_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `websiteCase_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK8BE8C2F05F1A4ADE` (`documentType_id`),
  KEY `FK8BE8C2F05C57B856` (`websiteCase_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8BE8C2F05C57B856` FOREIGN KEY (`websiteCase_id`) REFERENCES `WebsiteCase` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK8BE8C2F05F1A4ADE` FOREIGN KEY (`documentType_id`) REFERENCES `DocumentType` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `DocumentTypeInProgram` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cardinality` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `documentType_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `program_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK190E2A0A5F1A4ADE` (`documentType_id`),
  KEY `FK190E2A0AFCC6BB96` (`program_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK190E2A0AFCC6BB96` FOREIGN KEY (`program_id`) REFERENCES `Program` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK190E2A0A5F1A4ADE` FOREIGN KEY (`documentType_id`) REFERENCES `DocumentType` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Comment: your second query needs to group by both p2.id and wsc2.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, with a query that joins your two existing queries.  Like so:

```
select a.programId, 
       a.totalDocPerProgram, 
       b.upLoadedDocs, 
       (a.totalDocPerProgram - b.upLoadedDocs) as remainingDocs, 
       b.userSession
from (
    select p.id as programId, 
           count(dt.id) as totalDocPerProgram
    from DocumentType dt
    join DocumentTypeInProgram dtip on dtip.documentType_id=dt.id
    join Program p on dtip.program_id=p.id
    group by p.id) a
join (
    select p2.id as programId, 
           wsc2.id as userSession, 
           count(di2.id) as uploadedDocs
    from DocumentType dt2
    join DocumentInstance di2 on di2.documentType_id=dt2.id
    join WebsiteCase wsc2 on di2.websiteCase_id=wsc2.id
    left join Program p2 on p2.id=wsc2.program_id
    group by p2.id, wsc2.id) b on a.ProgramId = b.ProgramId
```

I haven't debugged this.  But this kind of thing works well, especially if you include a

```
 where b.userSession = constant
```

clause